# How to make json file by a payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am using Mobx on ReactJs.
When I get the payload by mobs state, it gives weird json or array like below code.
For example, I need 'a.l' like json file. But it doesnt work due to 'P' in the front of JSon type.
How can it be edit to make a normal json type?

```
P {G: Array(0), l: "AIzaSzyNbEXjtG475I", o: "[DEFAULT]", u: "cool-insure-bds6a.firebaseapp.com", c: bas, …}
```

Answer (score 0):

This string representation (with the leading 'P') is only appearing when you're converting your object to a string (with, for example, `console.log`).

Use `JSON.stringify(a)` in order to get a valid JSON string, which you can then write to a file or do something else with it.

If you want to get back to an array from that string, use `JSON.parse(str)`.

Comment: Thank you. But when I use JSON.parse again , i get this error "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0". Could you help me ?

Comment: @ThomasJason Can you show how you're calling `JSON.stringify()`? You should call it with the result of your payload. Make sure your server is also sending valid JSON, and not this "P { stuff }". If it's sending this, you should `JSON.stringify()` your data before sending to the client. Then you can use `JSON.parse()` from the client.